# VPM and RDP on MAC and Comcast, recently RDP won't work

Tags: wireless-networking, remote-desktop

At home I have a new XF router, internet is working without any problems.

However, I cannot connect over RDP to my work PC when I am connected to internet through this router (Wifi or cable).

If I connect my home PC (laptop) to a hotspot or from another internet connection (when I am travelling for example) the RDP connection works.

Apple said its xfinty or microsoft, Microsoft said its Apple or xfinity and well xfinity blame the other two, I'm frustrated at this point,  It all worked fine up until August 5th then all of a sudden the RDP keeps crashing with this message "We couldn't connect to the remote PC. Make sure the PC is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled. 
Error code: 0x204"
has anyone else had this problem and resolved it.  Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing your work PC is on a separate network? How are you RDPing to it by IP or are you resolving a hostname somewhere? Can you see if you can ping it? From your Macs terminal run `ping <work-pc-ip>`. If that works you can try and see if you can reach the standard RDP port with telnet. `telnet <work-pc-ip> 3389`. My first guess would be that the router is blocking some outbound ports so I'd run both commands on the router network and a hotspot. Take a look at your router config to try and fix it yourself and if you can't find the related setting forward your findings to your ISP.